# Asyncio gather exception_handler not working

Tags: python, exception, python-asyncio

I'm trying to use an exception_handler along with asyncio.gather

My code:

```
import asyncio

def exception_handler(loop, context):
    print('Exception handler called')

async def coro():
    print("coro")
    raise RuntimeError("BOOM!")
    return 1

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    loop.set_exception_handler(exception_handler)
    group = asyncio.gather(coro(), coro(), coro())
    results = loop.run_until_complete(group)
    print(results)

main()
```

When I run it, instead of getting a 'Exception handler called', I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 20, in main
    results = loop.run_until_complete(group)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 583, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "test.py", line 12, in coro
    raise RuntimeError("BOOM!")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the Python docs are unclear about what `asyncio`'s exception handlers are actually supposed to handle.

To quote Python core developer Andrew Svetlov from [this bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue39256):

> asyncio exception handler is supposed to catch *unhandled* exceptions only, not all raised ones.
>
> [...] an exception from a spawned task is not propagated to the parent task implicitly. That's why the exception is *unhandled* and passed to the registered exception handler.

The report gives the following example:

```py
async def test():
    raise Exception("Something goes wrong")

async def main():
    #Un-comment either 1 of the following 3 lines
    # await test() # will not call exception_handler
    # await asyncio.gather(test()) # will not call exception_handler
    # asyncio.create_task(test()) # will call exception_handler

    await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

In your case, you can handle exceptions like in any synchronous code:

```py
import asyncio

async def coro():
    print("coro")
    raise RuntimeError("BOOM!")
    return 1

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    group = asyncio.gather(coro(), coro(), coro())
    try:
        results = loop.run_until_complete(group)
    except RuntimeError:
        # handle exception
    print(results)

main()
```